# How can I validate JSON in VS Code using a schema file defined in the workspace?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I have followed the instructions in the VS Code documentation under Editing JSON with Visual Studio Code, Mapping to a schema in the workspace. I created a folder in the workspace root called json-schema and put a file called device_plugin_data_schema.json in it. Then I added the following to my settings.json:

```json
    "json.schemas": [
        {
            "fileMatch": [
                "plugin*.json"
            ],
            "url": "./json-schema/device_plugin_data_schema.json"
        }
    ],
```

When I open a file that should be validated with that schema, I get the following error:

Unable to load schema from '.\json-schema\device_plugin_data_schema.json': ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\json-schema\device_plugin_data_schema.json'.

It is supposed to use relative path but it is not?!

I am using VS Code Version: 1.81.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a relative path to something in a workspace folder for the url property of a JSON schema setting item, you need to define that setting in the [*workspace* settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_workspace-settings) (<workspace-folder-path>/.vscode/settings.json) instead of in the *user* settings. Related docs are [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_mapping-to-a-schema-in-the-workspace).

If you insist to define it in the user settings.json, I think you need to use an absolute path.

I think this is a sensible design. User settings apply to all workspaces, so if if relative paths were supported there, it would be an assumption that every single folder you open as a workspace would have a schema file that you'd want to use at such a path (presumably relative to the workspace folder, which I think would be a rather poor assumption, or lead to surprising users (in a bad way)).

Also note that if you want to specify schema files on a per-JSON-file-basis, you can use the `$schema` property in the JSON file you want to be validated to specify the schema to use.

Comment: wow, I feel dumb... I read the instructions from the csvode docs "Mapping to a schema in the workspace" and since the section above it was "Mapping in the User Settings", I did not register than it mean IN THE WORKSPACE SETTINGS!!! I was just reading it as the schema is in the workspace. So, ya, after reading your reply, that totally makes sense now that it has to be in the workspace settings instead of the user settings. I moved it and it works. Thanks so much!