# JSON Schema $ref to relative file path

Tags: json, schema

I am having an issue having my json schema work in Visual Studio 2022. It works in VS Code, but requires a restart now and again.

I have multiple files that contain different definition and reference them via a relative file path such as:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "$id": "ml-content-schema.json",
    "type": "object",
    "description": "Provides content for display",
    "properties": {
        "type": {
            "type": "string",
            "$ref": "ml-type-value.json"
        }
    }
}
```

The referenced file is in the same folder as the file doing the referencing. Also, have attempted to use ./ before the file name. Neither works.

Below is what is in the referenced file:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "$id": "../../v4/ui/schema/ml-type-value.json",

    "type": "string",
    "description": "",
    "enum": ["item1", "item2", "etc"]
}
```

I see at [JSON schema $ref does not work for relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145160/json-schema-ref-does-not-work-for-relative-path) the syntax I am using should be working, yet it does not.

Visual Studio 2022 give squiggly underline stating "Reference could not be resolved".

It does work in Visual Studio code, however co-workers are using Visual Studio and need intellisense for the json.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Potentially I am messing up the id value?

Comment: VS Code and Visual Studio are not the same thing. please fix your tags if this is a Visual Studio question. If this is actually a question about VS Code, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/76983871/11107541